# Finding square roots using approximations and loop

Tags: java, loops, square-root

this program is supposed to take a non negative integer and find the square root
The square root of a non-negative number n can be calculated successive 
approximations.  At each step, a new approximation is calculated as follows:

> next approximation = (n / current + current) / 2

The process of approximation continues until the value is close enough,
that is, the difference between (current * current) and n is small enough
to be acceptable.
However when i go print my answer nothing comes up. what am i doing wrong. is my loop not working correctly?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Squareroot1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a non negative integer: ");
        double n = in.nextInt();
        double result = approx(n);
        /*double current = result;
            while ((current * current)- n == Math.sqrt(n)) {
                double nextapproximation = (n/current + current)/2;
                nextapproximation = current;
                System.out.println(nextapproximation);
        }*/

        System.out.println( result);
    }

    public static double approx(double val) {
        double current = val;
        double approximation = (val / current + current) / 2;
        return approximation;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `aprox` function, what's the purpose of setting the variable `current` equal to `val`? Your aprox function seems to always return `(1 + val) / 2`, since `val` equals `current`.

Comment: Because the value that is current is the val for example if i enter 25 as a number to find the square root that is my current value that is being tested

Comment: If you step through your code, `current` gets set to `val`, so both variables are equal to, say, 25. Then, your approximation gets set to `(25/25 + 25)/2`, since `current` and `val` are equal. This applies every single time your function is called. I don't think that's what you're aiming for, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues:

1) Your while loop condition should be:

```
while ((current * current) - n != 0)
```

2) You are not setting `current` to the value of the `nextapproximation`

3) You are not printing out the final result (which should be current).

**The code**:

```
double result = aprox(n);
double current = result;
while ((current * current) - n != 0)
{
    double nextapproximation = (n / current + current) / 2;

    // Stop infinite loop
    if (nextapproximation == current)
    {
        break;
    }
    current = nextapproximation;
    System.out.println(current);
}
System.out.println("Result: " + current);
```

**Test Run**:

```
Enter a non negitive integer: 23
6.958333333333333
5.131861277445109
4.806832989404423
4.795844112917605
4.795831523329245
4.795831523312719
Result: 4.795831523312719
```

**EDIT**:

You don't need the `aprox` method and you don't need the `result` variable.

Before the while loop simply do:

```
double n = in.nextInt();
double current = (n / n + n) / 2;
```

Comment: it works when i enter 25 but when i enter 23 i get an infinint  loop

Comment: @Dem your welcome. glad I could help. Also, you don't need the aprox method and you don't need to result variable.. Before the while loop, you can use: `double current  = (n / n + n) / 2;`